# How to dynamic path for screenshot in Setting section of robot framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework, web-testing, selenium2library

i want to create one path for 1 time for save screenshot from testing 
Example 
1st  my path is

```
*** Setting ***
Library        Selenium2Library   screenshot_root_directory=/Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-00-00
```

2nd  my path is

```
*** Setting ***
Library        Selenium2Library screenshot_root_directory=/Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-30-00
```

How to set dynamic path

my robot code

```
 *** Setting ***
Library        Selenium2Library   screenshot_root_directory=/Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot
Library        DateTime
*** Variables ***

*** Keywords ***

*** Test Cases ***
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Goralight and me on the same page but i create global variable for saving path in Keyword

```
*** Setting ***
Library        Selenium2Library
Library        DateTime

*** Variables ***
${WEB}  xxx.xxxxx.xxxx
${BROWSER}  chrome
${TYPE OF FILE}  png
*** Keywords ***

Get DateTime
  ${date1}=  Get Current Date  result_format=%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S
  [Return]     ${date1}

Open Web
  Open Browser  ${WEB}   ${BROWSER}
  Maximize Browser Window
  ${Date}=  Get DateTime
  Set Global Variable  ${Path}  /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot/${Date}

Close Web
  Close Window

Screenshot
  [Arguments]  ${filename}
  Set Screenshot Directory  ${Path}
  Wait Until Page Contains  Element
  # ${datetime}=  Get DateTime
  Capture Page Screenshot  ${filename}.${TYPE OF FILE}
  Log To Console  ${\n}Screenshot


*** Test Cases ***

[1] Click Home
  Open Web
```

my folder result is

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nHV6.png)

Comment: Did you fix your problem or did the answer not fix it for you? Or? :s

Comment: i fix my problem  :) and thank you for your answer because it can build on to  my work .

Answer (score 1):

First specify the directory which you want the screen shot to be saved in - and set persist to False as it is a one time thing - for one particular test:

```
Set Screenshot Directory    /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-00-00    False
```

Then complete the the Screenshot - and check it exists:

```
${ScreenShotOne}    Capture Page Screenshot    Screenshot1.png
File Should Exist    /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-00-00/Screenshot1.png
```

Then, change the direcotry for the other Screenshot:

```
Set Screenshot Directory    /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-30-00
```

And then complete the same process you did above:

```
${ScreenShotTwo}    Capture Page Screenshot    Screenshot2.png
File Should Exist   /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-30-00/Screenshot2.png
```

You could also just set the path, every time you create the screenshot:

```
${ScreenShotTwo}    Capture Page Screenshot    /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-30-00/Screenshot2.png    False
File Should Exist   /Users/person/Documents/testrobot/screenshot30-01-2017 12-30-00/Screenshot2.png
```

All this was found within the Selenium2Library Documentation:

[Keyword: Capture Page Screenshot](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot)
[Keyword: Set Screenshot Directory](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Screenshot%20Directory)